# rails 3 arel eager load not working as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

```
class User
  has_many :subscriptions
  ...
end

class Subscription
  belongs_to :user
  ...
end
```

when i do a `User.includes(:subscriptions)`, the log says:

> User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users`
>   Subscription Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `subscriptions`.* FROM `subscriptions` WHERE
>   (`subscriptions`.user_id IN (1,2,3,5))

i would have expected a single join query, but i don't see it.

does anyone have an explanation for this behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the expected behavior, since it can be more efficient than a join in certain situations.  As of Rails 2.1, it was changed to execute at least 2 queries.  Read this as it relates to :include (now includes in Rails 3):

http://akitaonrails.com/2008/05/25/rolling-with-rails-2-1-the-first-full-tutorial-part-2

And more info in the rails guides:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations

You may want to use `joins` instead, depending on the scenario.